# Tabbed Bootstrap Modal Will Not Submit Forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal with tabs that is wrapped entirely in a form. When I have items for the form in just the first tab the form works successfully, but if I place any MVC helper objects in the other tabs, the submit button no longer works.

Here is code that works:

```
<div id="dialogDiv" class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Counterparty Request Details</h3>
    </div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditNewFullCounterpartyRequestDetails", "Counterparty",new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "dialogDiv",
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "ShowSuccess"
    }))
{
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.RequestDetails.CounterpartyRequestId)
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Request Details</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">KYC Matrix</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div>
                                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.RequestDetails.ContactEmail)
                                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RequestDetails.ContactEmail)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.RequestDetails.ContactEmail, "*Required", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div>
                                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.RequestDetails.ContactNumber)
                                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RequestDetails.ContactNumber)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.RequestDetails.ContactNumber, "*Required", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                        Coming Soon!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
}
</div>
```

Here is code that does not work:

```
<div id="dialogDiv" class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Counterparty Request Details</h3>
    </div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditNewFullCounterpartyRequestDetails", "Counterparty",new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "dialogDiv",
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "ShowSuccess"
    }))
{
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.RequestDetails.CounterpartyRequestId)
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Request Details</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">KYC Matrix</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div>
                                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.RequestDetails.ContactEmail)
                                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RequestDetails.ContactEmail)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.RequestDetails.ContactEmail, "*Required", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div>
                                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.RequestDetails.ContactNumber)
                                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RequestDetails.ContactNumber)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.RequestDetails.ContactNumber, "*Required", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.KycDetails.IsEscalated)
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.KycDetails.IsEscalated)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, and it turns out that it had nothing whatsoever to do with the modal tabs. I will explain as this may be useful to others. My model class had a component to it that did not have a default (no args) constructor. This component was being manipulated in the other tab, so when the "submit" button was clicked, the framework was calling a no-arg constructor that did not exist. The result is a silent failure.